# Is using a variable of type BYTE portable?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, portability

I noted that `windows.h` has this:

```
 typedef unsigned char BYTE;
```

I do not want to use this header file as I want my code to be portable.

Is there any other header file that defines `BYTE` in a way that is portable?

By portable I mean that it compiles on Linux systems.

Comment: Why do you need an external header file if you can just insert a typedef into your own code?

Comment: Just use `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned char` is by definition exactly one "byte" in size. A "byte" in C and C++ is exactly `CHAR_BIT` bits; `CHAR_BIT` is guaranteed to be *at least* 8, but it can be bigger.

If you need a byte, use type `unsigned char`.  You can use it directly, or you can define your own `typedef` such as

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
```

if you think it makes the code clearer (I don' think it does, but  YMMV).  Beware that you might use a library that defines its own `byte` or `BYTE` type.

The type `uint8_t`, defined in `<cstdint>` or `<stdint.h>`, is guaranteed to be an unsigned type of exactly 8 bits. On a system with `CHAR_BIT > 8`, `uint8_t` will not exist, since there are no objects (other than bit fields) narrower than one byte.

If you only care about portability to Windows and Linux, you can rely on `CHAR_BIT==8`; in that case, it probably doesn't matter whether you use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`.

If you want your code to be *really* portable, use `unsigned char` if you want bytes, or `uint8_t` if you need *octets* (which are by definition exactly 8 bits).

You haven't said what characteristics you want `BYTE` to have, so I can't be more specific than that.

Comment: @mans: The standard C headers (which are included in C++) have names of the form `<foobar.h>`. They define symbols in the global namespace (and when used from C++, they may or may not define the same symbols under `std::`). The C++ versions of these headers have names of the form `<cfoobar>`. They define symbols in the `std::` namespace (and may or may not define the same symbols in the global namespace). Either that, or I've misunderstood something, and a C++ expert will be along to correct me in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

Include `<cstdint>` and use `std::uint8_t` (or `std::int8_t` if you think of bytes as signed).  You can add a typedef if you want to use a different identifier, like `Byte`, rather then `std::uint8_t`.

```
#include <cstdint>

typedef std::uint8_t Byte;

...

Byte foo = 0;
```

That's the *most* portable thing to do.  On every mainstream modern platform, `unsigned char` is also always going to be equivalent to an eight-bit byte.